# How can I redirect if only a part of url match?

Tags: url-rewrite, ce-1.9.1.0, htaccess

I have 2 different domains:

- www.mysite.com
- www.mysite.it

and my product urls are something like:

- www.mysite.com/car-nissan.html
- www.mysite.it/auto-nissan.html

Can I use wildcard in Magento backend URL Rewrite Management to redirect?

e.g.:
www.mysite.com/car-*  <----> www.mysite.it/auto-*

Or I need to do this in .htaccess?

I tried something like:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^(.*)auto-(.*)$ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}/car-$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.it$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^(.*)car-(.*)$ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}/auto-$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using .htaccess and 'RewriteEngine' in this way:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.it$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^(.*)car-(.*)$ /$1auto-$2 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^(.*)auto-(.*)$ /$1car-$2 [L,R=301]
```